# Gnome and Cinnamon loads in fallback mode only

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, linux-mint, cinnamon

So I have been using linux mint for a while now. A few months ago my Gnome shell crashed and I was unable to use the full 3d features and loaded into fallback mode only. From that day (around 2 months ago) I still have only fallback mode (both Gnome and cinnamon).
I installed Linux mint maya, and Ubuntu 12.04 both as windows file and complete installation in an external hard drive. and for many times I sitll cannot fix this problem. 
ps I made sure to download all the drivers for my graphics card.
what could the problem be?

Comment: What do you do from a freshly installed system to download the drivers? Like, exactly what commands? What video card do you have?

Comment: To find video card, run "sudo lshw >> ~/Desktop/lshw-report-for-Andrew.txt" in the terminal and put it into your question, or on pastebin and give me the link.

Comment: lshw lists the hardware on your computer, and sudo lets it see all hardware on yoru computer, even hardware disabled for your account (which could be a problem)

Comment: Try creating a new user to check if it is simply something wrong with you user's settings.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/fjfsfVy4

Answer (score 0):

You can run following code in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo reboot
```